# Yii UrlManager: How use Ruby REST for .json and .xml files in my API?

Tags: yii

I'm creating a REST API in Yii and I'd like to build my URLs like this:

```
/api/my_model
/api/my_model.xml
/api/my_model.json
```

Where the first one returns the HTML view, .xml returns XML and .json returns JSON.

This is what I have in the rules for urlManager in main.php:

```
array('api/list/', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

I figure if I pass a format variable, then if it's blank I know it should return HTML, or json/xml if a format is passed.  I tried this:

```
array('api/list/', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>.<format:(xml|json)>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

And it works great for .xml and .json, but not when my url is just /api/list

My question is how do I setup the URLs in urlManager to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php regular expressions, `?` is used to match 1 or none of the previous character, so

```
a? means zero or one of a
```

Then we can use that in the rule:

```php
array('api/list/', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>.<format:(xml|json)>?', 'verb'=>'GET'),
// notice the ? at the end of format:
```

However the above will also allow urls of type : `api/my_model.`

To avoid that you can move the *dot* into the format variable :

```php
array('api/list/', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+><format:(.xml|.json)>?', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

But that will result in `format` being `.xml` or `.json`. So, we have another alternative:

```php
array('api/list/', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>(.<format:(xml|json)>)?', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

This should work with all urls, you wanted, and also match `format` as either `xml` or `json`.